# Why is PyQt connect() syntax so verbose?

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm just learning PyQt and looking at the Signals and Slots mechanism. I'm a bit baffled by the verbose syntax. Why do we have:

```
self.connect(dial, SIGNAL("valueChanged(int)"), spinbox.setValue)
```

I would much prefer to write the following:

```
self.connect(dial.valueChanged, spinbox.setValue)
```

Can anyone tell me why the connect() syntax needs to be so explicit/verbose?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use PyQt's [new style signals](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Signals_and_Slots_in_PySide) which are less verbose:

```
self.connect(dial, SIGNAL("valueChanged(int)"), spinbox.setValue)
```

Becomes:

```
dial.valueChanged.connect(spinbox.setValue)
```

Answer (score 2):

[Luper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17911/luper-rouch)'s answer is much better than this one, but for the sake of completeness...

The *ugly* "old style" syntax is an anachronism from the `C++` world - just look at the syntax those guys have to work with! [Yucky...](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#connect)

Answer (score 1):

An even shorter way is to assign the signal name to the function in the keyword arguments of the constructor e.g. `QDial(valueChanged=spinbox.setValue)`. PyQt will automatically connect the `valueChanged()` signal to `spinbox.setValue()`.