# Why does SLOT('insertColumn()') fail in PyQt binding?

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm diving into PyQt, and I've come across a little annoyance.  **SLOT('insertColumn()')** does nothing when attached to a button in the GUI.  **SLOT('clear()')** works perfectly, and **insertColumn()** works outside of the binding.  **insertColumn()** is listed as a public slot in the Qt documentation, so I'm stuck.

Here's the code:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args)

        # Table
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(6, columnCount, self);
        x = 0
        for x in range(0, columnCount):
            self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(x, 30)
        for x in range(0, 6):
            self.tableWidget.setRowHeight(x, 24)

        # Window geometery and layout
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('PyTab')
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tableWidget)

        # Menu and toolbar actions
        self.MenuExit = QAction(QIcon('exit.png'), 'Exit', self)
        self.MenuExit.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.connect(self.MenuExit, SIGNAL('triggered()'), SLOT('close()'))

        self.MenuAddColumn = QAction(QIcon('clear.png'), 'Add Column', self)
        self.MenuAddColumn.setShortcut('Ctrl+N')

        #This line works:
        self.tableWidget.insertColumn(2)

        # I'm not sure why this line isn't working:
        self.connect(self.MenuAddColumn, SIGNAL('triggered()'), self.tableWidget, SLOT('insertColumn(2)'))
```

I've tried defining the QTableWidget as **tableWidget** and **self.tableWidget**, but that didn't change anything.

Does anybody know what's causing this?

---

Here's the final code:

```
def add_column(self):
    tableWidget.insertColumn(1)
self.MenuAddColumn.triggered.connect(add_column)
```

It uses the new .connect() syntax as described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031489/why-is-pyqt-connect-syntax-so-verbose/4032125#4032125).  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `.connect()` only sets up the relationship for the signal and the slot. You can't actually pass values to the slot in the `.connect()` call. You can create your own slot and put that in the call to `.connect()` and then in your own slot implementation call `self.tableWidget.insertColumn(2)`.

Edit:
  Just to clarify..although the slot can't directly take values in the call to `.connect()`, it can receive parameters that are defined for the signal.

Comment: What is the syntax for creating a slot?  Is it the same as defining a function?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know python. It's pretty standard python/Qt usage though so it shouldn't be too hard to find an example. (or somebody with python/Qt experience will post a more complete answer for you)

Comment: Just define a method on your python class and pass it to connect instead of Slot(...)

Comment: @speedofmac, see [docs](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt3/PyQt.html#AEN589) for details, but basically you can pass any Python callable to connect() instead of the receiver/slot pair.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me figure that out.  I added the final code to the question.

Comment: @Sergey Tachenov, I was adding parentheses after the callable.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

While associating the signal with a slot you need to provide only the method signture and you shouldn't be passing the arguments to it. Also the signature of the method you provide as a slot should match the signature of the signal. As per the Qt docs
the signature of the *triggered* signal of QAction is as below: (Qt Version 4.7.0)

`void QAction::triggered ( bool checked = false )`

Essentialy you need to connect the triggered signal to a method that expects a boolean argument.

You can try having a code snippet like below : (untested)

`self.connect(self.MenuAddColumn, SIGNAL('triggered(bool)'),

self, SLOT('colAddition(bool)')`

```
def colAddition(self,value):  
    if value:  
        self.tableWidget.insertColumn(2)
```