# Which GUI frameworks are best for a multi-threaded Python program?

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, pygtk

I am writing a multi-threaded Python program with a GUI, with several modules that "touch" the GUI by changing text and background colors. I am currently using PyGTK and am finding that the GUI sometimes crashes "silently" (no error messages; the program just terminates), and sometimes encounters segmentation faults.

[This site](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?query=handlers&querytype=simple&req=search) notes that GTK is not completely thread-safe, and that PyGTK multi-threaded programming is tricky. Are there better Python GUI frameworks for multi-threaded programs that are less likely to produce problems?

Comment: GTK is not thread safe but it's thread aware , so you can definitely write multi-threaded code using GTK ; but yes writing multi-threaded code using GTK can be tricky actually when ever you try to write multi-threaded code using GTK or not, you will find you're self in spot like this one :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ohh, I definitely recommend [PyQt4](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro). At first, I didn't get all this `SIGNAL` and `EMIT` nonsense, but now that I've made a program with it, the `QThread` module is amazingly useful.

As for stability, I have never had a crash, ever. Even while I was debugging half-functional code, QT didn't have any problems. It just threw an error to the console window whenever I clicked a button with an invalid signal slot.

GTK, on the other hand, just 'sploded once in a while with no errors whatsoever. Just your extremely descriptive and friendly `Segmentation Fault`. That was one of the reasons I find PyQt a joy to work with. When you get an error, you actually know what's wrong.

I'm pretty sure it's personal preference after that, but one more plus is native-looking GUIs on Mac, Linux, and Windows. GTK+ on Windows (don't get me wrong. I use Ubuntu) just has this X-org feel to it, which disturbs me.

Good luck!

---

Just to make PyQt a bit more attractive, here's an excerpt from my book binding application (it's a bit messy):

```
class Binder(QtCore.QThread):
  '''
  Class for binding the actual book
  '''

  def __init__(self, parent = None):
    super(Binder, self).__init__(parent)



  def initialize(self, pages, options, outfile):
    self.pages = pages
    self.options = options
    self.outFile = outfile

    self.book = organizer.Book()
    self.enc = Encoder(self.options)
    self.ocr = ocr.OCR(self.options)

    self.connect(self.enc, QtCore.SIGNAL('updateProgress(int, int)'), self.updateProgress)



  def updateProgress(self, percent, item):
    self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('updateProgress(int, QString)'), int(percent), 'Binding the book...')
    self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('updateBackground(int, QColor)'), int(item), QtGui.QColor(170, 255, 170, 120))

    if int(percent) == 100:
      time.sleep(0.5)
      self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('finishedBinding'))



  def run(self):
    self.die = False

    for page in self.pages:
      self.add_file(page, 'page')

    if not self.die:
      self.analyze()

    if not self.die:
      self.book.get_dpi()

    if self.options['ocr'] and not self.die:
      self.get_ocr()

    if not self.die:
      self.enc.initialize(self.book, self.outFile)
      self.enc.start()
```

Comment: Signals and slots are far from non-sense, and recent PyQt and PySide offer a really nice interface to them.

Comment: Also take a look at new PyQts new style signals which make usage of Signal and Slots less verbose: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031489/why-is-pyqt-connect-syntax-so-verbose/4032125#4032125

Comment: I've reimplemented my GUI with PyQT4 and it seems to be working well. Qt Designer, coupled with pyuic4, was fairly easy to learn.  Based on discussions on Stack Overflow and elsewhere, it seems that it would be desirable to use the PyQt4 QThread module; because I already have other modules using Python's threading.Thread, I used a queue to modify a PyQt4 thread (see http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30708&seqNum=3; requires some slight modifications for PyQt4). So far, so good. Thanks!

Comment: PyQt is powerful because it's simple. That's why I use it. If you want to tinker with my application (I'm cleaning the code, so it might be messy), you can find it here: http://blender3d.github.com/Bindery/. Good luck with yours!

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating the GUI from a thread, you might want to use `gobject.idle_add()` so that the GUI update function is called later in the loop, most GUI frameworks (like Qt) require you to add a callback that will be called later when the mainloop is idle. GTK also supports calling the GUI functions from threads by using the `gtk.gdk.lock` context manager or calling `gtk.gdk.threads_enter` and `gtk.gdk.threads_leave` around your GUI calls.

So you either do:

```
gobject.idle_add(lambda: window.whatever(arg1, arg2))
```

Or you do:

```
with gtk.gdk.lock:
    window.whatever(arg1, arg2)
```

Comment: In GTK+, you need g_threads_{enter,leave} if you want to update the UI from outside the main thread, otherwise your app can crash randomly with very weird or no error messages. They are not supported in Windows, though, so for cross-platform apps you have to use g_idle_add.

Comment: Oh, right, now I remember I was calling g_threads_enter/g_threads_leave in my app, that's why it worked. I'll add it to my answer, thanks.